# how do i disable a widget based on the value of another widget in Kivy

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

I have a Spinner widget in a .kv file and I need the value of this Spinner to enable another Spinner widget.

This is the code i have tried and it does not work and gives me a Syntax error:

```
CustLabel:
    text: "Aux LO Pump Status"


CustSpinner:
    id: auxlo
    text: "Select"
    values: ('On', 'Off')
    focus: True
    on_state: (self.auxlonum.disabled) if (self.auxlo == 'off')

CustLabel:
    text: "Aux LO Pump Number"

CustSpinner:
    id: auxlonum
    text: "Select"
    values: ('# 1', '# 2')
    focus: True
```

i would actually prefer the auxlonum widget to start off disabled and 'greyed out' and then only be enabled if the auxlo widget had 'on' selected, however i was not sure how to go about this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you can´t use `on_state` event because it emit before you selected one value. You need use `on_text` event instead.

On the other hand, `self.auxlonum` is an incorrect syntax, you should use the `id` only to refer to any widget inside kv.

Finally, you only need to use the ternary operator syntax to do what you want:

```
Spinner:
    id: auxlo
    on_text: auxlonum.disabled = True if auxlo.text == 'Off' else False
```

Or:

```
Spinner:
    id: auxlonum
    disabled: True if auxlo.text == 'Off' else False
```

**Executable example:**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

from kivy.lang import Builder


Builder.load_string('''
<MyWidget>
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Spinner:
        id: auxlo
        text: "Select"
        values: ('On', 'Off')
        focus: True
        on_text: auxlonum.disabled = True if auxlo.text == 'Off' else False

    Label:

    Spinner:
        id: auxlonum
        text: "Select"
        values: ('# 1', '# 2')
        focus: True

    Label:
''')


class MyWidget(BoxLayout):
    pass

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):            
        return  MyWidget()

TestApp().run()
```

[image]

Comment: To start the kivy application with the spinner disabled, add `disabled:True` to the auxlonum spinner.